# How to manage balance on Stripe test card?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to use 4242 4242 4242 4242 card because it is a verified card. But is there a way I can change the balance of the card and set, for example, 1 dollar balance for it?

My system has verified the card, but I need this card to have low balance in order to get a warning about 'insufficient balance' when the payment process starts.

Comment: No that's not possible. Can you edit the question to describe in more detail what you're really trying to do and the exact scenario you want to test?

Comment: I want my payment system have a verified card. Then I need to test that if I try to pay using this card, it will give me the message 'insufficient balance'. In order to get this message, I need to have low balance on the card, so I'm trying to figure out how to make the balance on a verified Stripe test card low

Comment: You can charge 4000000000009995 directly, or you can attach the 4000000000000341 card to an existing customer and charge that, to simulate getting a decline charging a customer's saved card. https://stripe.com/docs/testing#declined-payments